# How to create a table with x number of months from a specific date for each unique item in a column

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a dataset loaded that produces a table that looks like Table 1.

What I'm trying to do is create another table that projects a certain number of months into the future from the most recent month in the dataset for each city, so I can essentially forecast the month-on-month decrease in the number of employees as shown in Table 2.

| City | Month Starting | Employees | 3 Month Average Attrition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Melbourne | `01/12/2012` | 105 |  |
| Melbourne | `01/01/2022` | 100 |  |
| Melbourne | `01/02/2022` | 98 |  |
| Melbourne | `01/03/2022` | 98 | 2% |
| Sydney | `01/12/2021` | 73 |  |
| Sydney | `01/01/2022` | 70 |  |
| Sydney | `01/02/2022` | 65 |  |
| Sydney | `01/03/2022` | 60 | 7% |

| City | Month Starting | Employees |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Melbourne | `01/04/2022` | 96 |
| Melbourne | `01/05/2022` | 94 |
| Melbourne | `01/06/2022` | 92 |
| Melbourne | `01/07/2022` | 90 |
| Sydney | `01/04/2021` | 56 |
| Sydney | `01/05/2022` | 52 |
| Sydney | `01/06/2022` | 48 |
| Sydney | `01/07/2022` | 45 |

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in powerquery

It first groups and sorts on date, to find latest date. I included the code to filter instead for data in the growth column if that is better. Then generate a list of 0..4 for the next 4 future months. You can set that in the code. Expand.  Then use that to calculate the future date using Date.AddMonths and math on the employee count

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"City", type text}, {"Month Starting", type date}, {"Employees", Int64.Type}, {"3 Month Average Attrition", type number}}),
// this next row (filter) can replace the following two rows (group/expand) if desired
// #"Expanded data" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([3 Month Average Attrition] <> null)),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows",{"City"}, {{"data", each Table.FirstN(Table.Sort(_,{{"Month Starting", Order.Descending}}),1), type table}}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Month Starting", "Employees", "3 Month Average Attrition"}, {"Month Starting", "Employees", "3 Month Average Attrition"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded data", "rows", each List.Numbers(1,4)),
#"Expanded rows" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "rows"),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded rows", "Month Starting 2", each Date.AddMonths([Month Starting],[rows]), type date),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Employees2", each Number.Round([Employees]*Number.Power((1-[3 Month Average Attrition]),[rows]))),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"Month Starting", "Employees", "3 Month Average Attrition", "rows"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks horseyride, I realised after trying this that I should've mentioned my "3 month Average Attrition" column is a DAX column and doesn't appear when I try to reference it in power query. Didn't know this would be an issue since I'm still fairly new to Power BI. I might just try and find another way to achieve what I'm trying to do here.